# Players turn was skipped, go back and allow that person to play out of order or continue on?

Tags: munchkin

Towards the end of a large game of munchkins with a good amount of alcohol consumed, a player’s turn was somehow completely skipped.

This player also somehow didn’t realize that he was skipped until AFTER the next person completed their entire turn.

So we initially wanted to continue on with a “you snooze, you lose” mentality. However he was adamant that he get his turn and we obliged him saying he can have his turn and then we will continue on from where we left off. He won the game that turn…

What are the rules concerning this? Should the player lose their turn if they were paying so little attention or were we correct in letting him go out of order?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your question basically boils down to "what are the rules for recovering from breaking the rules?"

Munchkin doesn't have such rules. But it does have the catch-all rule (from the [rulebook](https://munchkin.game/site-munchkin/assets/files/1138/munchkin_rules.pdf)) :

> Any other disputes should be settled by loud arguments, with the owner of the game having the last word.

So fix the error however the owner of the game decides: rewind game state, snooze-n-lose, play on as you did, or whatever.